# MariaDB Wrong data filling for UPDATE query with multiple joins

Tags: mariadb

I'm encountering a really strange issue with MariaDB which I can't seem to work out.

I have a query to fill the last date an item was ordered onto a product like the below:

```
UPDATE import_order_items oi
    INNER JOIN products p
        ON oi.product_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN import_orders o
        ON o.id = oi.import_order_id
SET 
   oi.last_sale_processed = NOW(), 
   p.last_sale_at = IF( p.last_sale_at IS NULL OR p.last_sale_at < o.created_at, o.created_at, p.last_sale_at )
WHERE oi.product_id != '0'
    AND oi.product_id IS NOT NULL
    AND oi.last_sale_processed IS NULL
    AND p.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND o.status != 'CANCELLED'
    AND o.status != 'DRAFT'
    AND o.status != 'PENDING'
    AND o.status != 'PAYMENT FAILED'
    AND o.status != 'PENDING APPROVAL'
    AND o.status != 'REFUNDED'
    AND o.status != 'MODIFYING'
    AND o.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY oi.created_at ASC
LIMIT 1
```

For the second field in the SET it is putting a different date to what is in the o.created_at field. I cannot work out where the date it is filling is coming from.

To check, I do a SELECT of the same query:

```
SELECT 
   p.id, 
   IF( p.last_sale_at IS NULL OR p.last_sale_at < o.created_at, o.created_at, p.last_sale_at ) AS last_sale, 
   o.created_at
FROM import_order_items oi
    INNER JOIN products p
        ON oi.product_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN import_orders o
        ON o.id = oi.import_order_id
WHERE oi.product_id != '0'
    AND oi.product_id IS NOT NULL
    AND oi.last_sale_processed IS NULL
    AND p.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND o.status != 'CANCELLED'
    AND o.status != 'DRAFT'
    AND o.status != 'PENDING'
    AND o.status != 'PAYMENT FAILED'
    AND o.status != 'PENDING APPROVAL'
    AND o.status != 'REFUNDED'
    AND o.status != 'MODIFYING'
    AND o.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY o.created_at ASC
LIMIT 1
```

This responds with the correct dates below and the first created_at date.

| id | last_sale | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1440 | 2016-10-15 11:33:00 | 2016-10-15 11:33:00 |

In the UPDATE however it will update a completely different order_item & product to the one above, and the date added does not match, it will come up with some random date which seems to be whatever the latest created_at date is in the import_orders table.

For example, it would update the import_order_item like so:

| product_id | created_at | last_sale_processed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1308 | 2022-08-19 23:11:36 | 2024-02-06 13:24:43 |

Wrong product as it is not the oldest.

Then it would update the product.

| id | last_sale_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1308 | 2024-02-06 10:30:21 |

The date does not match the import_order_item created_at, it is the latest import_order_item created_at from a completely different import_order_item.

The CORRECT action should have updated the earliest product with the date it was sold matching the SELECT query.

| id | last_sale_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1440 | 2016-10-15 11:33:00 |

I have the exact same query on different tables and it works perfectly. This one is not working though and I have no idea why. Any ideas?

Comment: How many orders do you gave on `2016-10-15 11:33:00`, because `ORDER BY o.created_at ASC LIMIT 1`  may not be correct. But I do not know because , not enough info....

Comment: There are a few items with each date. The order by is correct and works in the SELECT but not the update. The date it's using doesn't even match the order_item where it has set oi.last_sale_processed, but it is the matching product. It's very confusing.

Comment: Some sample data to make your problem a [mre] woud be nice.

Comment: I have added more details of what the results of the update are.

Comment: Can you create a DBFIDDLE (something like this: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/qpXNaP2Q))  but then with some more correct sample data which reproduces your problem ?

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to use LIMIT to set p.last_sale_at for *all* products, but it doesn't do that; it will only update one p row.

Comment: @ysth no, I want to update one at a time for testing, there are millions of order items in the table so I don't want to do it all in one query and kill the db. If it updates the one correctly I would update the LIMIT to do more at once. At the moment it's not doing the correct thing.

Comment: see Luuk's comment; please try to come up with a fiddle that demonstrates your problem using a small set of data